# how do I ssh from xterm in mininet-wifi?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox, xterm

I'm beginner using mininet-wifi.
I run my topology,So I want to run `ssh localhost` or `ssh 192.168.10.1` on station1 xterm.
but it doesn't work and returns `ssh: connect to host .... port 22:Connection refused.`.
I did change /etc/ssh/sshd_config and edited #port 22 to port 2222 but it didn't changed.
and still there was this error again.
could any one help me ?
In fact, I want to run python script server to listen and send data to another station, If some one has any idea about this is welcomed

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you add more details about the setup you made and which instruction or reference you are following?